# Entering the US after a change of status

Tags: visa, usa, visa-change

My wife and I are in the US. She has a B-2 visa and we plan to change her status to O-3. USCIS is supposed to send a new I-94 form after approving a change of status.

After changing the status to O-3, if my wife leaves the US and enters again with the B-2 visa and the new I-94 form, will she get a O-3 status?
Or must she apply for a new O-3 visa in a US embassy before entering the US again?

Surprisingly, the answer I get from different sources (USCIS and attorneys) are completely different. The attorney says my wife has to apply for a new O-3 visa, but several USCIS representatives (via USCIS website chat) told me that she would get an O-3 status with the B-2 visa + I-94.

Comment: What are the different answers you get from those different sources?

Comment: Can you post the specific quotes from USCIS suggesting she doesn't need a visa for reentry?  Then we can see whether they are actually wrong or if it's just a misunderstanding of ["visa" vs "status"](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/2729/visa-renewal-vs-status-renewal-for-us-visas).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't keep chat logs.

Answer (score 2):

Your wife cannot enter the US in O-3 status with a B-2 visa, except under [automatic revalidation](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/visa-expiration-date/auto-revalidate.html), which she can use only if she is returning from a trip of no more than 30 days' duration in which she has not gone anywhere other than Canada and/or Mexico.

Therefore, if she leaves the US under any other circumstances, she will need to get an O-3 visa at a US consulate before she can return.

Comment: Thanks @phoog. I updated my question. Any idea why the USCIS answer is different?

Comment: @ChronoTrigger did you give USCIS reason to think that she'd only be in Mexico and or Canada for 30 days or less before returning to the US?

Comment: No, I specified Spain.

Comment: @ChronoTrigger USCIS doesn't admit people to the US.  Maybe they gave that answer out of confusion.  Try asking CBP what they think.  I suppose their answer will agree with the lawyers.